# Can I use xampp's mysql to connect with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, xampp

It shows me connection error like

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
gem_original_require: no such file to load -- mysql (LoadError) 
from
C:/xampp/htdocs/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
require
from ruby_dbconnect.rb:4
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile you must have this line:

`gem 'mysql2'`

After editing your gem file you must run `bundle install` from the root directory of your application. Finally you must edit your config/database.yml file to ensure the connection parameters are correct